# How can I pass setup-code and processing-code to another process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a generic multiprocessing worker class that takes items from a queue to be processed. A user of the worker class would need to pass a function that processes each item. However, some processing functions need setup-code.

The current implementation uses a generator function that has to be correctly implemented by the user to correctly perform the setup code only once, process the items from the queue, and handle the StopIteration exception raised when the worker finishes normally.

Can a more straightforward and reliable method be used to separate the setup code from the processing code and handle the exceptions raised by the worker?

Here is what I have:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import typing

P = typing.Callable[[], typing.Generator[None, None, None]]
Q: typing.TypeAlias = "mp.Queue"


class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue: Q, processor: P):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.processor = processor

    def run(self):
        processor = self.processor()
        next(processor)  # start the processor
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get()
            processor.send(item)

            if item is None:
                break


class WorkerPool:
    def __init__(self, n_workers: int, processor_generator: P, queue: Q):
        self.workers = [Worker(queue, processor_generator) for _ in range(n_workers)]
        self.queue = queue

    def __enter__(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.start()

    def signal_end(self):
        for _ in self.workers:
            self.queue.put(None)

    def terminate(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.terminate()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is None:
            self.signal_end()
            self.join()
            return True

        self.terminate()
        return False

    def join(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()


class GeneratorWorkerManager:
    def __init__(
        self, item_generator: typing.Generator, processor_generator: P, n_workers: int
    ) -> None:

        queue: Q = mp.Queue()
        with WorkerPool(n_workers, processor_generator, queue):
            for item in item_generator:
                queue.put(item)
```

A user of the `GeneratorWorkerManager` class could do the following:

```py
def processor():
    # All sorts of setup code possible, including a with-statement. 
    item = yield
    while item is not None:
        # process item
        print(item)
        item = yield
    return


items = range(10)
GeneratorWorkerManager(items, processor, 1)
```

Where the worker would print 0 to 9. However, this relies on the user implementing the processor function correctly. The worker also raises a `StopIteration` exception when it finishes normally.

Is there a better way to use setup code and processing code in the same context?

Comment: You seem to have reinvented multiprocessing pools that are already supplied with Python as classes `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, which also provide a way to get return values from your worker function. One-time initialization is accomplished for each child process by specifying the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments to these classes' `__init__` methods,. This admittedly does not handle initialization that includes a `with` statement in any straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to pass a function that returns a context manager. Here I've wrapped the `open` function in another function as an example.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Callable, ContextManager, Iterable, TypeVar

I = TypeVar("I")
S = TypeVar("S")


class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(
        self,
        queue: "mp.Queue[I|None]",
        processor: Callable[[S, I], None],
        setup: Callable[[], ContextManager[S]],
    ):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.processor = processor
        self.user_setup = setup

    def run(self):

        with self.user_setup() as setup:
            while True:
                item = self.queue.get()
                if item is None:
                    break
                self.processor(setup, item)


class WorkerPool:
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_workers: int,
        processor: Callable[[S, I], None],
        queue: "mp.Queue[I|None]",
        setup: Callable[[], ContextManager[S]],
    ):
        self.workers = [Worker(queue, processor, setup) for _ in range(n_workers)]
        self.queue = queue

    def __enter__(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.start()

    def signal_end(self):
        for _ in self.workers:
            self.queue.put(None)

    def terminate(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.terminate()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is None:
            self.signal_end()
            self.join()
            return True

        self.terminate()
        return False

    def join(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()


class GeneratorWorkerManager:
    def __init__(
        self,
        item_generator: Iterable[I],
        processor: Callable[[S, I], None],
        n_workers: int,
        setup: Callable[[], ContextManager[S]],
    ) -> None:

        queue: "mp.Queue[I|None]" = mp.Queue()
        with WorkerPool(n_workers, processor, queue, setup):
            for item in item_generator:
                queue.put(item)


def custom_setup():
    return open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")


def custom_processor(setup, item) -> None:
    f = setup
    f.write(str(item))


items = range(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    GeneratorWorkerManager(items, custom_processor, 1, custom_setup)
```

It is not possible to use a setup function that does not support the with statement, but It would be easy to extend this with two setup variables, one for context-setup, one for regular setup.

Comment: `custom_setup` is *not* a context manager and so `worker.setup` will raise an exception. Also, the `Worker.setup` context manager does not seem to provide for custom-tailored code to be executed when the `with` block terminates, for example making a call to `close` on the opened file in your specific example. The solution, of course, is to  make `custom_setup` a context manager. See [demo](https://ideone.com/ZbXZn8).

Comment: No it's a function that returns a context manager, as the type indicates. Using the result of the function in with statement is thus safe. Admittedly the `@contextlib.contextmanager` is not needed. I will update the post

Comment: [This](https://ideone.com/qFwWlh) is how I would use a standard `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and a  *class* that implements the context manager protocol. It depends on garbage collection calling the '__exit__` method and I am therefore calling `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` to prevent my exiting before the daemon pool processes exit and thread local storage reclaimed. Do I know that garbage will always be collected before I exit? No, but this does seem to be the case here. But you may have many instances where you don't need teardown code and a much simple pool initializer suffices.